# 100% total width for flex items in flex container, with gap inbetween

Tags: css

I am trying to position elements in a flexbox with flex-wrap with gap in between

Ideally the way this should be displayed is:

- On the first row the blue box taking the full width no gaps anywhere
- Second row Red box taking the first 33%, Green box taking the remaining 66%
- There should be 12px gap between the 2 rows
- There should be 12px gap between the Red and Green item without them going on the next row, so their widths should actually become 33% - 6px and 66% - 6px so that there is space left for the gap.

End result should look something like this:

[image]

```css
.container {
 max-width: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 gap: 12px;
 padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
}

.item1 {
width:33%;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
width:66%;
height: 200px;
background-color: green;
}

.item3 {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item3"></div>
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: You can use [gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/gap)  its working for flexbox but please [check](https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap) support with Can i use. Other method - use margin for elements

Comment: The gap is working, but the flex-wrap is the problematic

Answer (score 5):

This a CSS grid use case where you don't need a lot of code and headaches:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-auto-rows:200px;
  gap: 12px;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item3"></div>
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a flex-direction: row, Removed the padding and added a calc function to the widths as well as upped the 66% to 67% to create 100% total.

```css
.container {
 max-width: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 gap: 12px;
}

.item1 {
width: calc(33% - 6px);
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
width:calc(67% - 6px);
height: 200px;
background-color: green;
}

.item3 {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item3"></div>
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I need the padding, its there intentionally

Comment: You might be able to use margin, otherwise just subtract the padding in the calc function as well

Comment: I thought of this approach but its becoming way too complex

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-basis` and `flex-grow` instead of `width`. See the example below...

```css
.container {
      max-width: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: 12px;
      padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
    }

    .item1 {
      flex-basis: 33%;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .item2 {
      flex-basis: 60%; /* Reduce this value abit and allow to auto grow */
      flex-grow: 1; /* Last item will fill up the remaining space */
      height: 200px;
      background-color: green;
    }

    .item3 {
      flex-basis: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="item3"></div>
      <div class="item1"></div>
      <div class="item2"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is @Ben variant but improve calculations

```css
.container {
  --gap: 12px;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--gap); // better use like veriable, you can edit it one time in all plays together
}

.item {
  height: 200px; // we have pattern, we don't need repeat it
}

.item1 {
  width: calc(33.33% - var(--gap) / 2); // improve calculation
  background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
  width: calc(66.66% - var(--gap) / 2);// improve calculation
  background-color: green;
}

.item3 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
</div>
```